# How to pass input variable from HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I'm trying to create a code which will take ask the user how many items of X, Y, etc and use Javascript to calculate the total owed and also to print a summary (receipt) of all items purchased.  Sorry for noob question, trying to learn code without any formal training. Thanks for all of the help!

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Cost Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function packageTotal(){
    //Enter in prices here
    var applePrice = 1;
    var bookPrice = 2;
    x = Number(document.calculator.books.value);
    y = Number(document.calculator.apples.value);
    var b = applePrice*x + bookPrice*y;
    var p = applePrice*x + bookPrice*y + .5;

    if (document.getElementById('noBag').checked) {
    //Basic package is checked
    document.calculator.total.value = b;
        } else if (document.getElementById('yesBag').checked) {
    //Pro package is checked
    document.calculator.total.value = p;
        }

    //Want to add summary of purchase
    //document.write("You want " + x " books and " y " apples.");


}
```

```
</head>

<body>

<!-- Opening a HTML Form. --> 
<form name="calculator">

<!-- Here user will enter the number of Books and Apples --> 
Enter Number of Books: <input type="text" name="books"> 
<br />

Enter the Number of Apples: <input type="text" name="apples">
<br />

<br />
<input type="radio" name="item" id="noBag" value="No" /> noBag
<input type="radio" name="item" id="yesBag" value="Yes" checked /> yesBag

<!-- Here result will be displayed. -->

<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="packageTotal();">

Your Total Price is: <input type="text" name="total">

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You said you wanted to do something and you posted, by the looks of it, code to do the aforementioned something. So whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question, but if this is the problem:

```
//Want to add summary of purchase
//document.write("You want " + x " books and " y " apples.");
```

then that would certainly break. `document.write` only adds to the current document when the document is still loading. If you call it afterwards it will implicitly open a new document to write to, destroying the current page. Generally `document.write` is a bad thing.

(also there are trivial syntax errors due to missing `+` concatenation operators)

If you want to write arbitrary text to the page, create a placeholder element:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

and then set its text content:

```
function setTextContent(element, text) {
    element.innerHTML = ''; // remove current content
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}

var message = document.getElementById('message');
setTextContent(message, 'You want '+x+' books and '+y+' apples.');
```

(There is a `textContent` property on elements which you can also use instead of the function, but it's not supported on IE<9 which use `innerText` instead. Simply writing the message directly to `innerHTML` would also work in this case, but it is a bad habit because it leads to HTML-injection security holes when used with user input.)